# How to save file to current year folder?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that exports a worksheet as a PDF file and saves it in the workbook location.

How would I save the PDF file into a folder labelled as the “current year”, e.g. 2020?
If there is no folder for the current year then one is to be created.

```
Dim StatementReports_Used As Range
Dim fullFileName As String
Dim saveLocation1 As String
Dim Y As Double
Dim X As Double
Dim year As Integer
year = Format(Date, "yyyy")
Y = DateValue(Now)
X = TimeValue(Now)
Dim dte As Date
dte = Now()
Dim numerical_date
numerical_date = Int(CDbl(dte))
Dim sourceDir As String
sourceDir = "C:\TextFolder\#19"
folder_exists = Dir(sourceDir & "\" & Str(year), vbDirectory)
fullFileName = "Text" & (StatementReports.Range("J20").Value) & "}" & "_" & Y & "_" & X  
saveLocation1 = Dir(sourceDir & "\" & Str(year), vbDirectory) & "\" & fullFileName & ".pdf"

StatementReports.ExportAsFixedFormat _
  Type:=xlTypePDF, _
  Filename:=saveLocation1, _
  Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
  IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
  IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
  OpenAfterPublish:=False

If folder_exists = "" Then
    MkDir sourceDir & "\" & Str(nowdate)
    MsgBox "A Folder for the Current Year has been created."
Else
    MsgBox "A folder for the Current Year Already exists. Your File will be saved to this."  
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have written. Where is the file containing the code located? If the file is in `C:\Test` where are you saving the PDF files, e.g. `C:\Test\PDF\2020`? How should the resulting name look like e.g. `WS31072020`.pdf? Consider rather using `YYYYMMDD` to have the files sorted in Windows Explorer i.e. `20200731`.

Comment: Hey @VBasic2008, 
Thanks for your message! Sorry I hadn't included the code with the original question. Kindly see the edited question with the code. 
Essentially what I would love to happen is that the file is saved into a year folder where the workbook is saved and if there isn't a folder already existing with the current year for one to be created. 
Re: Serial dates and times, all good :) I found an answer online using "Y = DateValue(Now) Y = DateValue(Now)"
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new folders is easy enough.

```
dim sourceDir as string
sourceDir = "C:\test_folder"

dim year as int
year = year(now())

' make the dir
mkdir sourceDir & "\" & str(year)
```

To get the date as an integer just convert it

i.e

```
dim dte as date
dte = now()

dim numerical_date
numerical_date = Int(CDbl(dte))
```

If you wanted to check if a folder exists first.

```
folder_exists = Dir(sourceDir & "\" & str(year), vbDirectory)

If folder_exists = "" Then
    MsgBox "The selected folder doesn't exist"
Else
    MsgBox "The selected folder exists"
End If
```

That should do the trick for you

EDIT:

Full code as you asked so nicely :)

```
Sub savePDF():

Dim dte As Date
Dim numericalDate As Integer
Dim sourceDir As String
Dim year As Integer
Dim reportWs As Worksheet
Dim folder_exists As String
Dim fullFileName As String
Dim pdfFileName As String
Dim folderPath As String
Dim filePart As String

    'set worksheet as current
    Set reportWs = Application.ActiveSheet
    
    ''OR
    ''set reportWs = worksheets("Worksheet_name")
    
    'get year
    year = Trim(Str(Format(Date, "yyyy")))
    
    'get date
    dte = Now()
    
    'get numerical date
    numerical_date = Int(CDbl(dte))
    
    'source directory
    sourceDir = "C:\TextFolder\#19"
    
    'check if folder exists, if it doesnt them create a new directory
    folder_exists = Dir(sourceDir & "\" & year, vbDirectory)
    If folder_exists = "" Then
        MkDir sourceDir & "\" & year
        folder_exists = Dir(sourceDir & "\" & year, vbDirectory)
    End If
    
    'get folder path
    folderPath = sourceDir & "\" & folder_exists
    
    'get filename (I dont think you should use the DATE and TIME as you have as the characters are invalid) Please change below format as you see fit.
    filePart = reportWs.Range("J20").Value
    fullFileName = filePart & numerical_date & " " & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy HH_MM_SS")
    
    'PDF save locaiton
    pdfFileName = folderPath & "\" & fullFileName
    
    'Save PDF
    reportWs.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=pdfFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the late reply! 
Thanks for sharing that code, it worked as intended. 
Would there be a way for me to make the "save location" of the exported PDF file, as the folder year even if there's already one existing? At the moment it throws out an error when there already is a folder with the current year. 
Sorry guys I had forgot to include some of the code in the original post. Kindly see the edited original question. 
Sorry if some of the questions may be a little obvious, I'm completely to coding with VBA. Thanks in advance for all your help!!

Comment: I've updated my answer, don't forget to tick it - if it was helpful to you :)

Comment: Hey Lewis, Really sorry for the late reply! So your little code has work an absolute treat and has done exactly what I would like it to!! :) Although if you are happy to lend some more assistance, I've actility no idea how to get the PDF file to either: "Save into current year folder if existing" or to "create a current year folder if non existing and then save into that" (I've updated the OP code to reflect your working changes) 
Stay safe everyone!

Comment: Sorted it for you :) I would suggest changing the `application.activesheet` to the commented out section. But I wasn't sure of your workbook name. I've also changed the output file name as i think you were a bit confused with the "Text" section. I could be wrong and you might want it there.

Comment: You're an absolute marvel!! Working exactly as imagined. Thank you so much for your guidance and assistance has been super helpful! Cheers - Will